# Python unittest setUpClass cannot call method from base class

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am using the unittest framework from Python, and run into issues when setting up a class for a test case. I would like to call a method from the base class in the setUpClass() method as follows:

```
class TestA(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestA, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.variable = "hello"

    def do_something(self):
        print(self.variable)
        return self.variable

class TestB(TestA.TestA):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):

        var = cls.do_something()
```

But I get an error saying that I cannot call do_something().

```
TypeError: unbound method do_something() must be called with TestB instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

I have no idea how (and if) I can call a method from the base class as part of the setUpClass method.

What am I missing?

Comment: do_something() is an instance method and can't be accessed from class method

Comment: can you explain more? or propose an alternative solution?

Comment: Imagine we are talking about a car. We can calculate the maximum amount of bags we can put into the luggage compartment of specific type of car because this calculation is a class method - we don't need an instance of a car for this calculation. Therefore class method doesn't need "self" to work. But if we want to drive a car, we definitely need one because driving is an instance method. "self" is required in this case. Trying to drive a car when there's no car results in "unbound method drive()".

Comment: great, perfectly clear now. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `super()`.

```py
>>> class Base:
...     def do(self):
...             print('base is doing something')
... 
>>> class Child(Base):
...     def better_do(self):
...             super().do()
...             print('much better')
... 
>>> 
>>> c = Child()
>>> c.do()
base is doing something
>>> c.better_do()
base is doing something
much better
>>>
```

A class method, however, is bit different. You must call the class itself.

```py
>>> class Base:
...     @classmethod
...     def cls_do(cls):
...             print('Base class is doing something')
... 
>>> Base.cls_do()
Base class is doing something
>>>
```

Comment: Static method and class method are not the same in Python. And OP's issue is not about how to call a class method. The problem is you can't call instance method from class method (unless instance is explicitly passed to class method i.e. as an argument).

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I do not understand your point. If you don't feel my answer is adequate please provide an adequate answer yourself, or suggest concrete changes I should do to mine. My understanding is that the OP does not a have a concrete understanding of instance/static/class methods, so I gave one. To provide a better answer the OP must add more detail, and I believe this is the source of your comment.

Comment: I agree that OP doesn't understand the difference between instance/static/class methods. I pointed out that in your last paragraph you wrote about a static method but the code sample uses class method. My second point is that in OP's code the exception is thrown within class method on an attempt to call instance method. I have no doubt you understand why it doesn't work, since you proved your knowledge. I believe you simply mistyped static instead of class method. It's hard to say whether OP should use setUp() method instead of setUpClass() or change do_something() to become class method...

Comment: ... because we are missing the context. I don't think one can write significantly better answer than yours unless this is clarified.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Thank you. A typo indeed. I've corrected it. I meant _class method_.